# Ruby on Rails CanCan, allow users to choose roles on signup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I'm a bit confused on how this works. I've been following some tutorials, and what I'm stuck is how do I know which user that signs up has certain permissions?

For example, I like to have users choose between two different roles:

Business or Resident on a signup screen

Am I supposed to add these role names in my console into the Role table? Or is there an easier way to add these two different role types into my database?

I have added

```
  <% for role in Role.find(:all) %>
    <div>
      <%= check_box_tag "user[role_ids][]", role.id, @user.roles.include?(role) %>
      <%= role.name %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

But nothing shows in my view. I'm assuming because I have no specific role names in my database, its not showing.

Is console the best way to just add the roles? Or is there another method that I can go for so in the future, I can easily manipulate thing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three possibilities for doing come to mind:

1. Create an administrative interface to enable admin roles to add additional roles via the MVC
2. Add new roles via the console, as you mentioned
3. Seed your database

If admins have access to the Rails console (and assuming they know how to use it), option 1 seems like overkill *unless* you already have other admin functionality rolled into the MVC.

Personally, I would opt for the last option. It's as easy as adding through the console, but provides the added benefit of actually committing a history of your changes to code.

The nominally simplest way of seeding your DB is using `seeds.rb`. In it, you can write whatever commands you need to properly seed your database on either an initial or subsequent seed:

```
# db/seeds.rb
cities = Role.create([{ name: 'Business' }, { name: 'Resident' }])
```

Then, from command line, run `rake db:seed`. All statements in your `seed.rb` will be run in sequence. If there are any errors (or other issues, like duplicate records), ActiveRecord will treat them accordingly (i.e., you don't need to worry about silent failures).

As a note, there are several seeding libraries out there that might facilitate the seeding process. I haven't personally used it, but the workflow of [Seedbank](https://github.com/james2m/seedbank) seems to make sense.